# How Can I Add New Data in Laravel Sheets Integration?

Tags: laravel

The issue is actually that I cannot add new data to the existing table. It's asking me to create a new table. When I try to add data to a table with the same name, it also gives an error.

> "{\n  "error": {\n    "code": 404,\n    "message": "Requested entity was not found.",\n    "errors": [\n      {\n        "message": "Requested entity was not found.",\n        "domain": "global",\n        "reason": "notFound"\n      }\n    ],\n    "status": "NOT_FOUND"\n  }\n}\n"

My code

```
 $sheetName = 'Sheet 1';

            $newData = [
                ['4', 'name4', 'mail4'],
            ];

                Sheets::sheet($sheetName)->append($newData);

            $values = Sheets::all();
```

https://github.com/kawax/laravel-google-sheets
The package I'm using is a part of Kawax. I've followed the instructions provided here, but I still can't make new data entries on the same page.